# How to test for directly returned component?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

How do I test for a directly returned component? I am using jest/enzyme for testing and my example component just returns another component.
My test is failing for that, but I don't know how to fix that.

**example.js**

```
import Something from './Something'

export const Example = (props) => {
  return <Something {...props} />
}
```

**example.test.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Example } from './Example'
import { Something } from './Something'

test('should render Something component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Example {...props} />)
  expect(wrapper.find(Something)).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

Comment: this is strange. what `wrapper.debug()` shows you?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could test if it renders correctly by doing a `snapshot` test:

```
describe('Something component test suite', () => {
  test('It renders correctly', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<Example {...props} />)

   expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Here is *jest* docs about snapshot testing https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test('should render Something component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Example {...props} />)
  expect(wrapper.find(Something).length).toEqual(1)
})
```